# How can i make a metronome with jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance, tempo, adjustable

This doesn't have to be with a clicking sound.
I need something to visualize a certain tempo/ metronome

How can I make a sound or image appear on a certain tempo?
So maybe with `fade` or `toggle()` but then with a tempo which you can
adjust in an input field.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function metronomeTick() {
   $("#metronome").toggle();
   setTimeout("metronomeTick()", 1000*60/$("#bpm").val());
}

metronomeTick();
```

The JavaScript `setInterval()` method is generally discouraged as it doesn't keep the function "execution time" (how long it takes to, for instance, actually visualize the tick) in mind. On second thought, setInterval would be even better in this case, since it's time-critical.

With `setInterval()`, the code would look something like:

```
var intervalReference = setInterval("metronomeTick()", 1000*60/$("#bpm").val());

function metronomeTick() {
  // Do tick visualisation here, but make sure it takes only a reasonable amount of time
  // Less than 1000*60/bpm, that is
}

$("#bpm").change(function() {
  clearInterval(intervalReference);
  intervalReference = setInterval("metronomeTick()", 1000*60/$(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Okay thank you for this answer, I tried it in jsfiddle, how can i let a user adjust the bpm/speed?

Comment: My code examples are reading the value of the #bpm textfield, so just add an <input type="text" id="bpm" val="120" /> to your page.

Comment: Ofcourse my bad! Now i have this; jsfiddle.net/kN3rM/
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: how can i add an arm and animate the same

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should look at some animation extensions and parameters for easing.
you can start here http://api.jquery.com/animate/
and maybe you can grab some code from this example: http://www.irengba.com/codewell/loop.html